# Rails: Devise Admin Retain Password on Editing User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, admin

I created the New/Edit User's page so Admin can add and update Users. Now what I am trying is this: when the the Admin edits a User, the Admin has the option of not updating the password, only the email. But how will I retain the password after saving the updated email?

Edit Page:

```
 <div><%= f.label :email, 'Email Address' %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control", autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Enter email address"  %></div><br />

  <div><%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Enter password"  %></div><br />

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Confirm password"  %></div><br />
```

Model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Controller:

```
  def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to edit_user_path
    flash[:notice] = "User updated."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the password field is empty or not, if it's empty than use devise's `update_without_password` method, try this

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if params[:user][:password].blank?
    if @user.update_without_password(params[:user].except(:password, :password_confirmation))
      redirect_to edit_user_path
      flash[:notice] = "User updated."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  else
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to edit_user_path
      flash[:notice] = "User updated."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```